What does ".NET Framework 4.8 (package-provided)" mean
Recently I noticed a new term in Microsoft documentation: .NET Framework 4.8 (package-provided). For instance, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.rfc3161timestamprequest?view=netframework-4.8-pp.
What dose package-provided mean? I cannot find any documentation.

It means this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs

package-provided means they're not included in the framework install itself so to use them you'll have to manually add the package reference through Nuget, though some templates, dependencies, or IDEs may helpfully add it for you on project creation or while typing the code reference.
This is clarified by the dev in https://github.com/dotnet/apisof.net/issues/16

We have the notion of platform APIs and package APIs. Basically, a platform provided API is part of the .NET runtime/framework whereas a package provided API requires referencing a package.

I can't find a blog post/doc that mentions the policy/decision in general, but usually a library/API is distributed through Nuget if Microsoft assumes they're relatively niche, or if they want to distribute updates without having to update the framework entirely.
